# ImportError when I try to run a .py script using CherryPy

Tags: python-2.7, importerror, cherrypy

I'm using python 2.7 and cherrypy 3.7, and am running them on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have a simple hello world file that I am trying to run with the command:

```
python HelloWorld.py
```

This results in the following error:

> ImportError: No module named cherrypy

Please explain why Python couldn't find the module.

Comment: It seems that you don't have `cherrypy` installed correctly. If you're using Ubuntu, you can try `pip install cherrypy`. Then issue `python -m cherrypy.tutorial.tut01_helloworld` and go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

Comment: I installed pip and then entered the command and got:

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cherrypy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Then I tried entering both 'python HelloWorld.py' and 'python -m cherrypy.tutorial.tut01_helloworld' and got the same ImportError as before.

Comment: We don't put "solved" in a question title here. Marking an answer "accepted" serves that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu is going to have a native version of python 2.6 for instance.  So you'll need the full path to your python file.  Try to run this and if it fails search your system for a python2.7 folder.

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 tut01.py
```

Hope this helps!